# How to declare a two-dimensional array with 2 variables values

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to declare a twodimensional array with a value `int size` but I don't know how to do it.

I want to do this:

```
int size;

class tile {
public:
    tile() : val( 0 ), blocked( false ) {}
    unsigned int val;
    bool blocked;
};

tile board[size][size];
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable length arrays as standard. Just use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector< std::vector< tile> > board( size , std::vector<tile> ( size ) );
```

will do it.

Alternatively,

```
tile** board = new (tile*) [size]; //allocate the array as a whole
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)     //now allocate each row in it
   board[0] = new tile [size];
```

But vectors are definitely the way to go.